# Linking Scip with CPLEX or Gurobi

Tags: python, optimization, cplex, gurobi, scip

Is it possible to link CPLEX or Gurobi with the windows installer .exe of the scip optimization suite (Version 7.0.2)?
Or do i have to build scip with cmake/make to configure an other LP solver? Is there any step-by-step installation guide i could follow for installation?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you have to build SCIP yourself (I recommend using cmake since it is much more platform-independent).

I suggest you look at the INSTALL.md file in the scip folder (after you download the scip sources) for an installation guide.